# PHP: How to call data from set Session

Tags: php, session

New to php. I am building a login system profile.
I want to show a dynamic url by set session username with userid but this snippet echos all the users in the table.
Tried using `$var = $_SESSION['username'];` doesn't work.

Any fix? Thanks

```
<?php
    $get_user = "SELECT * FROM users";
    $run_user = mysqli_query($con, $get_user);

    while ($row_user=mysqli_fetch_array($run_user)) {
        $user_id = $row_user['userid'];
        $user_title = $row_user['name'];
        echo "<li><a href='profile.php?user=$user_id'>$user_title</a></li>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: You need to read a sql book and a php book first...you need to understand about what are you doing first, before coding.

Comment: Not really sure what you're trying to do. This code selects all the users from the database and iterates through them one by one and echos a link to each. If you only want a specific user, use a `WHERE`-statement.

Comment: ...I'm not really seeing how the above code is related to a "login system" or has anything to do with sessions.

Comment: I am new to this. sorry if i'm that dumb. I have a set session login system. i just want to make a dynamic url by selecting the set session. so that i can make a profile page. for each individual user.